# windows script host javascript - find/run program with variable path using regular expressions

Tags: javascript, regex, wsh

Trying to run a program with a path `/release/0.0.0.100/program.exe` where `/release` always contains only one folder with a changing version number in the pattern of `\d.\d.\d.\d\d\d`. Is there a way to find `/` and run the program using wsh javascript or other scripting language?

Comment: too lazy to work out the details, but the documentation you need is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee236359%28v=vs.84%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This regex will do the match part, I modified your expression so that the dots where also escaped `\.`. In a regular expression a `.` means to match any character whereas an escaped dot `\.` will match a literal dot `.`. Depending on the language you may also need to escape the slashes so they look like `\/`

`\/release\/\d\.\d\.\d\.\d{3}\/`

Although if your version numbers could ever contain double digits like the 23 in `1.23.4.555` you should consider adding some plus signs to require 1 or more digits between the dots.

`\/release\/\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d{3}\/`